# BLE onConnectionStateChange called twice when closing a connection

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Finally got my device (based on TI's CC2541) to work with my phone (a prototype/non-commercial-yet phone running Android 4.3). I can scan, discover, connect and get notifications successfully. However, when I disconnect (calling BluetoothGatt.disconnect()), the onConnectionStateChange callback is called with newState=STATE_DISCONNECTED (as expected) but then immediately called again with newState=STATE_CONNECTED. 
The connection is definitely terminated so I'm not sure why I'm getting the 2nd onConnectionStateChange call. Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Comment: Is your device bonded? I vaguely recall some autoconnection happening for bonded devices but like I say it's vague. I've also had unreliable BLE results depending on the device's physical stack, so you may want some vendor data on the stack's stability and compatibility with the new 4.3 BLE API.

Comment: I have exactly same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check the status given to you in onConnectionStateChange; if the status isn't 0 (OK) then you didn't actually get a connection. I've found a number of occasions where I get the CONNECTED message but the status was indicating something else was happening.